# snappy-java test error:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: snappy

I have a snappy-java-1.1.7.2.jar file.
first, I wrote a TestSnappy.java

```
import org.xerial.snappy.Snappy;
public class TestSnappy {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        String input = "Hello snappy-java! Snappy-java is a JNI-based wrapper of "
            + "Snappy, a fast compresser/decompresser.";
        byte[] compressed = Snappy.compress(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        byte[] uncompressed = Snappy.uncompress(compressed);

        String result = new String(uncompressed, "UTF-8");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Then, I use

```
javac -cp snappy-java-1.1.7.2.jar TestSnappy.java
```

Finally, I tried

```
java TestSnappy
```

but I got

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(I)I
        at org.xerial.snappy.SnappyNative.maxCompressedLength(Native Method)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.maxCompressedLength(Snappy.java:376)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.rawCompress(Snappy.java:419)
        at org.xerial.snappy.Snappy.compress(Snappy.java:101)
        at TestSnappy.main(TestSnappy.java:11)
```

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After a while, I tried set `CLASSPATH=SOMEWHERE/snappy-java-version.jar`, It worked.